# Swift UITableView will not resize to a larger size

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a segmented control that allows a user to select the size on an image in the UITableView. when the user selects a size that is smaller than the last, the tableview resizes and reloads perfectly but once a user clicks on a size larger than the current size, nothing happens. I have print statements in my code so I know that each cell is being remade to the right constraints and size but the tableview still shows the same as it was before selecting a larger size.

```
var imageSize:FLoat = 160

func changeImageSize(){ // this is called when the segmented control is selected
    if imageSizeTab.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        self.imageSize = 140
    } else if imageSizeTab.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        self.imageSize = 200
    } else if imageSizeTab.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        self.imageSize = 240
    }
    print("changing image size to ", self.imageSize)
    self.viewableListingsTableView.reloadData()
}

// this is a summary of the creation of the cell. simplified for the sake of this question
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.viewableListingsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom", for: indexPath) as! listingCellTableViewCell
    cell.height = self.imageSize
    cell.layoutSubviews()
}

// this is the UITableView class
class listingCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var height:Float? {
        didSet {
            self.setupView()
        }
    }
}


// I deleted the creation of irrelevant views to be easier to read
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.addSubview(titleView)
    self.addSubview(firstImageView)
    self.addSubview(distanceView)
    self.addSubview(priceView)
}

func setupView() {
    print("changed image size to ", self.height ?? 0)
    let h = self.height ?? 160
    print("changed h to ", h)
    self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(h)).isActive = true

    //self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    firstImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    //firstImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor)
    firstImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    firstImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(h)).isActive = true
    firstImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(h)).isActive = true

    titleView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: CGFloat(h + 6)).isActive = true
    titleView.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.width - CGFloat(h) - 12
    titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.6).isActive = true
    titleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    priceView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: CGFloat(h + 6)).isActive = true
    priceView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
    priceView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: distanceView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    priceView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true

    distanceView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: CGFloat(h + 6)).isActive = true
    distanceView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
    distanceView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -6).isActive = true
    distanceView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
 }
```

Comment: instead of using this one layoutsubview use layoutifneeded, and override a function in table view cell with name of update constraints. just update constraint for image. keep in mind if your cell size is 100 and you want to change image size 240 it does not work. you need to update your cell size as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because it uses a reusable cell, I had to clear all the constraints before changing them. for example: imageview.removeConstraints(imageview.constraints())